# LPSolve C++ source и IDE выдают разные результаты решения задач Линейного Программирования

Tags: c++

У меня имеется оптимизационная задача линейного программирования, для ее решения я использую LP Solve (были опробованы две версии:v-5.5.2.3, v-5.5.2.0).
Недавно появилась проблема - в IDE выдает одно решение (я считаю что оно верное), а программная реализация - другое (совершенно отличное, и я считаю неверное). Как я проверял: с помощью программных функций (set_upbo(lp, i, l);
set_mat(lp, 0, i, 0);), обращаясь к LP Solve составлял задачу в объекте решателя, после чего запускал на решение

```
int result = solve(lp);
```

и выводил полное решение и составленную целевую функцию, уравнения и ограничения в два файла. После чего полученные уравнения в формате LPSolve передал в LPSolve IDE и получил следующие результаты: 

**UPD**

**------------------------------------------------**

Для примера:

```
/* Objective function */
max: +y4 +y5 +y6;
/* Constraints */
n1: +x4 -y4 -z4_5_4 -z4_6_5 +z5_4_8 +z6_4_9 = 0;
n2: +x5 -y5 +z4_5_4 -z5_6_6 +z6_5_7 -z5_4_8 +z6_5_10 -z5_6_11 = 0;
n3: +x6 -y6 +z4_6_5 +z5_6_6 -z6_5_7 -z6_4_9 -z6_5_10 +z5_6_11 = 0;
/* Variable bounds */
x4 <= 15060;
x5 <= 17550;
x6 <= 17150;
y4 <= 15000;
y5 <= 15000;
y6 <= 15000;
z4_5_4 <= 2000;
z4_6_5 <= 2000;
z5_6_6 <= 1000;
z6_5_7 <= 1000;
z5_4_8 <= 2000;
z6_4_9 <= 2000;
z6_5_10 <= 1000;
z5_6_11 <= 1000;
```

приведенное выше уравнение выдает следующий результат в LP Solve IDE:

```
Var-s    Result
         45000
x5       15060
x4       17000
x6       12940
y4       15000
y5       15000
y6       15000
z4_5_4   0
z4_6_5   60
z5_4_8   0
z5_6_11  1000
z5_6_6   1000
z6_4_9   0
z6_5_10  0
z6_5_7   0
```

**------------------------------------------------**

Далее с помощью функции get_variables(lp, var); в режиме Debug посмотрел полученное решение:

```
Var-s    Result
         45000
x4       15000
x5       15000
x6       15000
y4       15000
y5       15000
y6       15000
z4_5_4   0
z4_6_5   0
z5_4_8   0
z5_6_11  0
z5_6_6   0
z6_4_9   0
z6_5_10  0
z6_5_7   0
```

После чего менял входные параметры ограничений (целевая функция и уравнения не меняются) однако IDE мне выдавал примерно такие же значения или немного изменные, а программа проктически всегда 15000 и 0. 
На каком то форуме читал что можно заменить значения *"1E-5"* вместо *"0"* и *"1000"* вместо "1.0", поменялась целевая функция получилось что используются минимумы всех значений, меняется решение но оно не верно.
Таким образом мне нужно чтобы программная реализация выдавала решение идентичное IDE, если у кого-нибудь есть идея в чем может крыться ошибка, с удовольствием выслушаю и опробую все способы решения проблемы.

Comment: Не совсем ясно: если целевые функции равны в обоих решениях, то как удалось понять, что одно из них неверное? Проверить на правильность можно, например, так: решить двойственную задачу, и если целевая функция будет иметь то же значение, значит оно верное. Есть и другие способы. Затем подставить переменные в ограничения задачи: они должны удовлетвориться. А тот факт, что задача ЛП может иметь бесконечно много решений - так это очевидно.

Comment: Понять удалось следующим образом - действительно значение целевой функции одинаковое (45000) однако значения переменных в случае решения программным способом равны только 15000 и 0 и это при условии что каждый раз ограниченная немного меняются примерно на 100. В моем случае если в переменные помеченные символом z равны 0 то задача не решена. Я понимаю если бы значения в IDE LPSolve и программной реализации отличались незначительно, там бы конечно стало понятно что где-то найдено более оптимальное решение. Но в моем случае оптимум вроде как и найден, а значения по которым идет статистика, всегд

Comment: Видите ли, в чём дело, все эти решатели стремятся оптимизировать целевую функцию в условиях ограничений. Если целевая функция приняла оптимальное значение, то любое из подходящих значений переменных может быть выдано. Если нужно, чтобы переменные имели иные значения, то добиться этого можно ТОЛЬКО новыми ограничениями. Например, напишите там `z>=1`, тогда z не будет равно нулю, если вас это не устраивает. Короче, всё зависит от задачи, поэтому когда у вас такая проблема, то это точное свидетельство неверно сконструированной модели.